# How to define an app's screen orientation from another app in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an app from where I can get the list of all installed application with their icon. Here is my code:

```
package com.powergroupbd.appfilter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ApplicationFilterActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ListView appfilter;
    // ArrayAdapter<Applications> adapter;
    PackageManager pck;
     ArrayList<Applications> results = new ArrayList<Applications>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        appfilter = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvApp);

        PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> applist = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
        Iterator<PackageInfo> it = applist.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            PackageInfo pk = (PackageInfo) it.next();
results.add(new Applications(pk.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager), ""+pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)));
            Log.i("AppName", ""+pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
}

         Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<Applications>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(Applications c1, Applications c2) {
         return c1.getAppname().compareToIgnoreCase(c2.getAppname());
         }
         });

        appfilter.setAdapter(new Customarrayadapter(this, results));
    }
}
```

but now i want that if I click on a list item then that particular app will open in Landscape orientation from the next time, I need Idea how can I do this?

Comment: Can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal experience is that what you are trying to do is impossible. Forcing an application to only be shown in landscape mode cannot be done from another app. If I understand you correctly you want to open the selected app in landscape mode even if the device is in portrait, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct, but I am sure that its possible , because this type of app is already in google play
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.rotator_t#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwibmV0LnhkZXZlbG9wLnJvdGF0b3JfdCJd